# How can I set POST data to null if not alphanumeric?

Tags: php, validation

I am posting allot of form data to my query. I want to set POST data to null or remove the special characters if not alphanumeric and the rest keep there values?

Is there a quick way I can do this in bulk?

```
if (!isset($_POST) || !ctype_alnum($_POST)){

// POST equals null 
}else{

// Nothing 
}
```

Comment: `$_POST` is an array, so it will never be alpha-numeric. Try iterating through the values of the `$_POST` array with a `foreach` loop and check if each value is alpha-numeric.

Comment: I would also not recommend treating an unsubmitted form the same as a form with validation errors. That is likely to confuse your users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
{
    if (empty($value) || !ctype_alnum($value))
    {
        // remove non alphanumeric chars
        $_POST[$key] = preg_replace("/[^[:alnum:]]/i","",$value);

    }
}
```